# git log --first-parent shows "wrong" commit message

Tags: git

context : I was trying to have a "clean" master branch, so I played with the options `git merge --squash` and `git rebase -i HEAD~x`, but for both I encountered problems (mainly because I don't really understand git) :

what I have :

```
      C - D - E
     /         \
A - B - - - - - F
```

and I would like to see a "clean" log history :

```
A - B     -     F
```

I finally discovered that I can manipulate the log output instead of changing the history, I think that is great :

using `git log --first-parent master` gives me (simplified) :

```
F "merged commit"
B "second commit"
A "first commit"
```

but there is something that I don't understand : if I changed the commit message of `F` with `git commit amend -m "third commit"`, I will still get :

```
F "merged commit"
B "second commit"
A "first commit"
```

even though `git log --graph` output :

```
* F "third commit"
|\
| |
| * E "feature third commit"
| |
| * D "feature second commit"
| |
| * C "feature first commit"
| |
|/
* B "second commit"
|
|
* A "first commit"
```

so, why isn't `git log --first-parent master` showing me the amended message ?

Comment: By the way, to see things in more detail, add `--decorate` to your `git log` command, or set `log.decorate`. It should generally be set to `auto` in modern Git, but you might have an ancient Git version, or you might be piping your `git log` output: `auto` means "turn on when going to my terminal window, but off when going to a pipe or file or other program".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git commit --amend` option does not *change* a commit.  It makes a *new and different* commit.  When Git does this, it updates *one* branch name, specifically the *current* one.

Suppose the original sequence of commits goes like this.  Note: I tend to draw them horizontally with newer commits towards the right, rather than as `git log --graph` draws them with newer commits towards the top:

```
     C--D--E   <-- your-branch
    /       \
A--B---------F   <-- master (HEAD)
```

That is, you're using the name `master` as the *current* name, so that `git log --graph --first-parent master` will show you commits `F`, then `B`, then `A`, but so will `git log --graph` without the branch name `master`.

Now suppose that instead of the above, we have this:

```
     C--D--E   <-- your-branch
    /       \
A--B---------F   <-- dev (HEAD), master
```

This is the same *graph*, so `git log --graph --first-parent master` will start at commit `F`, then jump back to commit `B`—skipping over the second-parent `E` and its ancestors—and show you what you expect.

Now, using this same setup, let's run `git commit --amend` and make note of the fact that it does not *change* commit `F` at all.  Instead, it makes a new (and supposedly improved) `F'` that's *like* `F` but has something different in it: in this case, we change the log message.  So now we have:

```
     C--D--E   <-- your-branch
    /      |\
A--B-------\-F   <-- master
    \       \
     --------F'  <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Running `git log --graph --first-parent`, you'll see your new `F'`, then `B`, then `A`, in that order.  But the only *name* that `git commit --amend` updated was `dev`, not `master`.  So `git log --graph --first-parent master` will show commit `F`—the original, not-actually-amended-at-all commit—and then `B` and then `A`.

What this means for you is that you must be *very careful* with `git commit --amend`.  It needs the same care as `git rebase`, which *also* works by copying existing commits to new-and-supposedly-improved replacement commits.  **The original commits always remain.**  No commit can ever be changed, not even by Git itself!  **If** nobody ever *sees* the original commits any more, it looks as though the old commits have been changed into the new ones, provided you never look at the raw hash IDs.<sup>1</sup>  But they haven't: the original commits are still there, with their original hash IDs.  We're just using the updated name to find the *new* commits *instead of* the old ones.

The care is required because some people—in this case, maybe even yourself—will still have names that refer to the *old, un-improved* commits.  When using those names to find commits, they will see the old commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>And who does that, anyway?

Comment: thx ! great explanation ! so, if I use `git log --graph --first-parent branch` I have to be careful at the creation of the commit, such as when I use the method of `git merge squash` I need to do the right manipulation at the merge time. The only method that would allow me to "rework" the log history at any time would be the `git rebase -i HEAD~x`, but I don't succeed with it so far :p anyway, thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Both rebase and amend make *new* commits, then *move a branch name* (just *one* name). Using `git merge --squash` makes one new ordinary (non-merge) commit, which adds on to the current branch as usual: `git commit` *also* moves *one* branch name, to account for the newly added commit.

Comment: You could, in the above example, forcibly move the name `master` to point to the same commit that the name `dev` points to after the `git commit --amend`. Just remember that *if* any *other Git repository* has the commit whose hash ID `master` used to name, they will still have a name for the *old* commit. You'll need to send them the new commit *and* convince *them* to update all *their* names!